# How to solve '[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named ...'?

Tags: rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 12.04

ROS Hydro

I am a freshman to ROS, recently I create nodes according to the book ‘Learning ROS for Robotics Programing Second Edition’,

but after I execute ‘rosrun’, something strange happend:

rosrun chapter2_tutorials chap2_example1_a

It shows that:

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named chap2_example1_a below /home/exbot/dev/catkin_ws/src/chapter2_tutorials

Actually, the executable chap2_example1_a exists in  /home/dev/catkin_ws/devel/lib

I think something is wrong with the path. But I am not sure.

How to solve it?
Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220455/how-to-solve-%27%5Brosrun%5D-couldn%27t-find-executable-named-...%27?/) by [ChenJinluo](https://answers.ros.org/users/24992/chenjinluo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2015-11-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2015-11-05**:
Can you show us the output of `catkin config`? Perhaps you need to  `sudo apt-get install python-catkin-tools` for that.

Do you have multiple catkin workspaces on your machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most probably you need to source devel/setup.bash

[see here for similar question](http://answers.ros.org/question/220415/problem-with-ros-tutorial/#220417)

---

Originally posted by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) with karma: 789 on 2015-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChenJinluo](https://answers.ros.org/users/24992/chenjinluo/) on 2015-11-05**:
Thanks.
But it doesn't help.
In the end of my ~./bashrc, I already have `export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/dev/catkin_ws:/home/exbot/rosbuild_ws/sandbox:/home/exbot/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks`  If I add `source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` in the end. It even can't find

**Comment by [ChenJinluo](https://answers.ros.org/users/24992/chenjinluo/) on 2015-11-05**:
my package.  `[rospack] Error: stack/package chapter2_tutorials not found`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-06**:
Don't set `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` yourself, let `setup.bash` of the appropriate workspace do that. Remove that line (`export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=..`), and change `source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` to source the `setup.bash` from your workspace (ie: `devel/setup.bash`). Then open new terminal, and try again.

**Comment by [ChenJinluo](https://answers.ros.org/users/24992/chenjinluo/) on 2015-11-06**:
It works! Thanks a lot ^ ^